# Android Studio Unable to open class file Manifest.java

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have a eclipse-based Android project, I migrated to Android Studio without Gradle build system, when I compile the project, it reports this error:

```
Error:android-apt-compiler: [android_test] ERROR: Unable to open class file C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.AndroidStudio\system\compile-server\_temp_\android_apt_output8444765104196896598tmp\com\marktola\test\Manifest.java: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Other people can compile it without error message in Mac

Comment: Use the Gradle build system. There is no way around it. That is most likely what the others are doing. They're using Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have the Gradle build for your project , without this you cannot build your project in Android studio.

Assuming you would be making changes in your project as you are Importing your project in Studio , I would recommend to activite the Graddle build.